# Get a JSON text

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have this JSON text:

```
data = {"one":"number","two":"string","three":"number","four":[{"five":"number","six","string"},{"five":"number","six":"string"}]}
```

How I can get "five"'s number and "six"'s string using Python 3.3 and using json module ?
P.S.: If I do `print data['five']` it doesn't works with this error:

> print(data['five'])
>
> KeyError: 'five'

Thanks,
Marco

Comment: Have you tried `print data['four'][0]` or `print data['four'][1]`

Comment: I think you need a colon between "six" and "string" in your `data` dictionary.

Comment: which `"five"` and `"six"`? there are two `dict`s in `data['four']` that contain those keys, in your example it wouldn't matter but which are you after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
data = {"one":"number","two":"string","three":"number","four":[{"five":"number","six":"string"},{"five":"number","six":"string"}]}

print(data['four'][0]['five']) # number
print(data['four'][0]['six'])  # string
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is a metod for print:
Five:number and Five:number2 togheter?

Comment: not 100% sure what you're looking for but try `print(data['four'][0]).values()`.

Comment: Also `print(data['four'][0])` prints the whole sub-dictionary.

Comment: It's print:
"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'values'"

Comment: ...and {"five":"number","six","string"}

Comment: oh you're using python 3... `print(data['four'][0].values())`

Comment: But i'm not sure the exact output you want